# JQuery change event does not fire on load on password field when remember password is enabled in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So here is the issue:
On my login form, if the user has not entered in the username AND password, then the login button will be disabled. This works fine. In Chrome, if you have remember password enabled, the page will load and the username and password field will get populated, but the login button will remain disabled. Here is the JS:

```
var submitBtn = $('#authSubmit');

$('#username').bind('keyup click mousedown paste change input',function(){
        if ($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') {
            submitBtn.removeAttr('disabled');
            submitBtn.removeClass('customDisabledBtn');
            submitBtn.addClass('customButton');
        } else if($('#email').get(0)) {
            if($('#username').val() != '' || $('#email').val() !== '') {
                submitBtn.removeAttr('disabled');
                submitBtn.removeClass('customDisabledBtn');
                submitBtn.addClass('customButton');
            }
        } else {
            submitBtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            submitBtn.addClass('customDisabledBtn');
        };
    });
$('#password').bind('keyup click mousedown paste change input',function(){
    if ($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') {
        console.log($('#password').val());
        submitBtn.removeAttr('disabled');
        submitBtn.removeClass('customDisabledBtn');
        submitBtn.addClass('customButton');
    } else {
        submitBtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        submitBtn.addClass('customDisabledBtn');
    };
});
```

On page load, that console.log will not log anything. However, once you click anywhere on the page, the function will run again and the console.log will log the correct password, and the login button will become enabled.  This is not the desired behaviour. If remember password is enabled, then the login button should be enabled when the page is loaded. I have tried to trigger the click manually after this function runs, but no luck.

Anyone know if there is a bug with Chrome in the area? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="authLogin" name="authLogin" method="post" action="/auth/dologin">
    <fieldset id="formFieldset">
                <p class="formField contentTextIcons">
                    <label for="username"><?= $this->siteLabels['UserName']; ?>:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                </p>
                <p class="formField contentTextIcons">
                    <label for="password"><?= $this->siteLabels['Password']; ?>:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="loginBtns clearfix">
                <p class="loginBtn">
                    <button id="authSubmit" class=""><?= $this->siteLabels['SignInBtn']; ?></button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/jbekis/2hbvv95r/3/

But the issue is that in Chrome when you have your password remembered, the function does not see it until after you click anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Could you show your html code. A jsFiddle would help too.

Comment: You could try with a `setTimeout` or even a `setInterval` to check if its populated. And maybe try to add `autocomplete="off"` to the input fields.

Comment: have you written this inside $(document).ready()?

Comment: @Sushil yes, this fires from $this->view->docReadyJS in the controller.

Comment: @andybeli I have added a link for the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JsFiddle you have the following first

```
if($('#username').val() == '' && $('#password').val() == ''){
    submitBtn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    submitBtn.addClass('customDisabledBtn');
}
```

Which intends to disable the button. Notice the following condition will disable the button if **both** fields are empty

```
$('#username').val() == '' && $('#password').val() == ''
```

You want to disable the function if **any** of both are empty, so it should be

```
$('#username').val() == '' || $('#password').val() == ''
```

Which produces the desired behaviour [in your JsFiddle with said correction](https://jsfiddle.net/jbekis/2hbvv95r/3/)

Also you should consider abstracting the behaviour of disabling the button into a function to avoid code repetition